# Paradox of Drawing Samples from Countably Infinite Urn?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity, paradoxes

Consider the following two countable sets of numbers $A = \mathbb{N}\smallsetminus 7 \mathbb{N}$ and $B = 7\mathbb{N}$, i.e., the set of natural numbers that are not multiples of 7 and the set of all multiples of 7. It is easy to prove that $|A| = |B|$.

Given these facts, I have been twisting my brain around the following thought experiment that I came up with - imagine you have an infinitely large urn that contains the elements $A \cup B = \mathbb{N}$. The probability that a random element drawn out of this urn is divisible by 7 = $\frac{1}{7}$ even though, according to cardinality, there are an equal number of elements in from both sets in the urn! In fact this argument would suggest that there are 6 times as many numbers in set $A$ than there are in set $B$!

Going strictly by the sizes of the sets, it seems like it should be equally likely to pick elements from set $A$ and from set $B$ which is even stranger since from empirical evidence we know that the probability should be $\frac{1}{7}$.

How do we resolve this paradox? I feel that I have misunderstood some concept pertaining to cardinality of sets, but then again, $\infty$ is a pretty weird monster on its own and hence I am expecting some interesting responses!

Comment: This shows that probability on infinite sets is not about cardinality, it is about how the elements are arranged. Take a dart board. The board has the same amount of points (uncountably many) as an arbitrary short and infinitely thin line on its surface. Still, hitting the line has probability 0 and hitting the board has (hopelfully) probability 1. You should better think about [*measure*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) than cardinality.

Comment: You have empirical evidence of an infinite urn containing infinitely many balls?!

Comment: @DavidHartley I meant intuition and not empirical evidence :)

Comment: @M.Winter but what I find stranger is that the measure of  any point in an uncountably infinite set is 0 which means that the probability of drawing any random number from $\mathbb{R}$ is also 0 which still confuses me

Comment: @BanachTarski I always calm myself with the fact that this is a fault of the model and not of the reality. You will never run into such problem in reality when you think it to the end. But yes, dealing with infinities requires some compromises.

Answer (score 1):

Probability theory (PT) allows you to argue in a consistent way about such questions. If you want to bring in PT you have to set up a space $\Omega$ of elementary events $\omega$ (here $\Omega={\mathbb N_{\geq1}}$), a $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal F}\subset{\cal P}(\Omega)$ of measurable events, and a $\sigma$-additive measure $\mu:\>{\cal F}\to[0,1]$. If you accomplish this – it can be done in several ways, but not in the "intuitive" way – then the paradox will disappear.

E.g., you could fix a large number $N$ and put $$\mu(A):={1\over N}\sum_{1\leq x\leq N} 1_A(x)\ ,$$ or you could put
$$\mu(A):=\sum_{x\in A}2^{-x}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious bijection between the intervals $A = [0,1)$ and $B = [1,4)$, yet if we define a uniform random variable $X$ whose support is on the union of these intervals, the probability of $X \in A$ versus $X \in B$ are not equal, because when we say "uniform distribution," we have imposed a **probability measure** on the sample space $A \cup B$.

Comment: Still, in OP's case the probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$ is the one that counts cardinality, not the Lebesuge measure like your example. I believe that the chance of picking a number in $B$ is one half.

Comment: @barmanthewise Indeed, and as your own answer states this explicitly, yours is the reason why I resorted to the example I gave, since it illustrates that the mere existence of a bijection between sets does not mean that the sets necessarily have the same measure.  They *could*, depending on how you define the probability space, but they don't *have to*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this. You can't really talk about probability in the natural numbers. You would have to construct a function $\mu:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow [0,1]$.

You immediately see that this is not possible taking cardinality into account. If, like in your case, you have an infinite set $A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ then $$\mu(A) = \frac{|A|}{|\mathbb{N}|} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$$.

I don't know if it is actually possible to come up with some wacky $\sigma$-additive function that would get you a probability, but for sure it wouldn't be related to the intuitive notion of cardinality.